# Monitoring bandwidth usage per domain on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, fedora

I have an AWS EC2 instance running Fedora. It hosts multiple domains. How do I find out the bandwidth / network usage of each domain? There are several tools but I specifically need "per domain" info. I'd like to keep a tab on which domain-owner is exceeding the network bandwidth. TIA.

Answer (score 2):

With just an EC2 instance, you cannot find out the network usage for each domain with AWS tools.

This is because AWS simply offers you an IP address for the EC2, and there is nothing looking into the HTTP / HTTPS level which would make it possible to report per-domain statistics.

One option would be to install a web server log analyzer software, which then generates statistics on your virtual hosts, and there you can see the bandwidth used.

AWStats and Webalizer are options for that.

Another option is to install an ELB for each domain, then you can see the traffic for each domain. However, that is too excessive approach for this situation, and not the use-case ELB is designed for.